# Stack and Heap memory effects?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

In the following code:

```
MyClass oMyClass1;
MyClass oMyClass2 = null;
```

My doubt is how the above two lines will affect memory (stack & heap).

Will create reference in stack?

Answer (score 3):

> my doubt is how the above two lines will affect memory(stack & heap).

Insufficient information, 2 possibilities:

1. they are local variables. In that case those 2 lines make 2 identical allocations (of a reference, always 32/64 bits) on the stack (whenever and for how long the method is executed). No allocations on the heap.
2. they are fields in a class or struct. In that case those 2 lines each allocate the size of a reference in the instance when it is created. That instance could be allocated on the stack (when they are struct members) or on the heap (class members).

Comment: +1 After edit to make distinction between structs and classes in point 2.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it depends on where the code is.

If the code is in a regular function/method, it will affect the stack only. There will be no effect on the heap, because no MyClass objects have been constructed yet.

Assuming MyClass is a class (i.e. reference type), the declarations will each reserve enough space on the stack to hold a reference to a MyClass object.

The two declarations are slightly different - the first one has not been initialised, so any attempt to access oMyClass1 before it is set to something will give a compiler error. The second one is initialised, so you will not get a compiler error [although you will get a runtime error if you access a method or property of oMyClass2 before you set it to refer to an actual object, e.g. with oMyClass2 = new MyClass();].

If the code is inside a class declaration:

```
class Fred {
    MyClass oMyClass1;
    MyClass oMyClass2 = null;
}
```

then it will only be executed during the Fred constructor. The space (for a Fred object, including space for two MyClass references) will already have been allocated on the heap before the constructor is called. The two lines of code will actually have no effect, as the space will already have been initialised to null.

If it is inside a struct declaration, the effect will be similar, only on the stack (if the struct is local) or global variable memory (if the struct is static). [Although, to be fair, I'm a tiny bit unsure where statics get allocated in C# - I am just assuming it is done in a similar way to C++]

Comment: As I already said in a now-deleted answer, instances of value types that aren't class members are *not always stored on the stack*. If they're captured by a lambda expression or an iterator block, they'll be stored on the heap instead.

Comment: The references will only get allocated on the stack if they are locals. If they are class members they will be on the heap.

Comment: @Frédéric It's worth detailing that if they are captured by a lambda, they are no longer "locals". They will be converted to references to properties on a closure class i.e. a wrapper object. The closure sits on the heap.

Comment: @chibacity, true, the "locals" would indeed be "promoted" to members.

Comment: @chibacity - I think you are just restating what I wrote in the answer. If the answer is actually wrong, I would be grateful if you would explain how (I might learn something!) But thanks for the comment to Frédéric - that was how I was thinking of it too - lambda expressions, anonymous delegates, Linq, etc. are just shorthand ways of creating extra classes, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Nikki Was my comment before your answer edit? I think you'll find it was. There is an edit history you know...

Comment: The phrase "If the code is in a regular function/method, it will affect the stack only" was there in the original. But if you were merely saying the same thing I later added in my edit, sorry for jumping on it. I'm a bit touchy after someone marked down one of my answers which was entirely factually correct, because they failed to read it properly!

Comment: MyClass oMyClass1; // this will occupies memory in stack and hold's address of WHAT?
MyClass oMyClass2 = null; // this will occupies memory in stack and hold's NULL?

Comment: oMyClass1 "does not have a value". What bit pattern is used to represent this is irrelevant - you can not find out what it is using conventional code, because any attempt to access the value is a compile time error (you could use a debugger to examine the memory location, if you really wanted to know - I suspect it will be null). oMyClass2 will be null.

Comment: @Nikki If oMyClass1 is a member variable it will be initialized to its default value e.g. null if it is a class. The fact that the OP has not made it clear whether they are locals or fields confuses the issue, however, if we assume it is code that will compile, then they must be fields. If they are fields then they are both initialized to null, furthermore, initializing a reference field to null is redundant: this happens by default.

Comment: There is no reason why this code should not compile if the variables are locals - there is no use of the oMyClass1 variable shown, so the code is legal as it stands. Clearly there is later code that is not shown, that we must assume either sets oMyClass1 to a value before it is used, or never uses it (in which case there will be a compiler warning).

Comment: I just noticed someone down-voted my answer. In order to help me make my answers more acceptable to SO users, I would be glad of an explanation why. I promise not to argue!